# Golang not enough arguments in call to client.Ping

Tags: golang

Я новичок в Golang, но нужно срочно решить проблему
Выдает ошибку `not enough arguments in call to client.Ping`
Предыдущий разработчик уверяет, что все раньше работало, и это могло быть из-за обновления библиотеки

```go
func Init() {
    var err error
    redisUrl = config.MustString("redisUrl")
    redisPassword = config.MustString("redisPassword")
    redisDb = config.MustInt("redisDb")
    client = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     redisUrl,
        Password: redisPassword,
        DB:       redisDb,
    })
    _, err = client.Ping().Result()
    if err != nil {
        logger.StdErr().Warn("Can`t connect to redis server! ", err.Error())
    } else {
        logger.StdOut().Info("Connected to redis!")
    }

    go _syncWithDB()
    go _sendWorkToBroker()
}
```

Comment: Не все скопировалось
Текст ошибки

 not enough arguments in call to client.Ping
        have ()
        want (context.Context)

Comment: вы привели код, который не издает ошибку, а который издает — не привели даже импорт на него :) кроме импорта не забудьте еще go.mod (отрывок с нужной либой) привести

Comment: Спасибо!
Да я новичок, мне в Go приходится на лету разбираться :)

go.mod

 github.com/go-redis/redis v6.15.9+incompatible // indirect

В main.go вызов тут

func init() {
 flag.Parse()
 err := config.Init(config.NewFileProvider(configPath))
 if err != nil {
  panic(err)
 }

 logger.ReloadLogs()
 global.Init()
 db.Init()
 broker.Init() // вот этот вызов
}

А ругается именно на номер строки с client.Ping() в коде, приведенном выше. Не совсем пойму, какой именно код нужно выложить. Сори) Мне всунули эту задачу, я на другой технологии работаю

Answer (score 1):

В корне проекта должен быть файл `go.mod`. Там нужно проверить версию загруженного модуля `Redis`. Скорей всего используется `Redis` последней версии.

Предположим код раньше работал, тогда версия должна быть <8, т.к. контексты в качестве параметров были добавлены в 8 версии.

Можно попробовать синхронизировать зависимости (чтобы убрать лишние)

```
go mod tidy
```

И добавить пакет заново (v6.15.9+incompatible)

```
go get github.com/go-redis/redis@latest
```

---

UPD:

Нужная версия пакета в `go.mod` отмечена как `// indirect` т.к. ещё не импортирована.

Проверьте импорты в файле где находится `Init()`.

Скорей всего там `github.com/go-redis/redis/v8` вместо `github.com/go-redis/redis`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало! :)

Comment: тогда отметьте решением :)